# How to add "" double code in variable in bat file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written bat file to get path from system variable using `%JAVA_HOME%` and assigned it into one variable, now how to use as set path, because in set path its asking me this path between **" "** code, which i am not able to add in.

Please help me to add it, how ?

Comment: who is asking for what?

Comment: understanding your question is one thing, understanding your problem is another thing, i'm confused

Comment: This question is not about Java, but about Windows batch files. Please show us what you've tried and what error message you get - that will make it much easier to understand what you are trying to accomplish and help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to  set JAVA_CMD="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java"  hard coded into bat file, which is working file, but I have to set path dynamically.

Comment: I cannot find anything about 'dynamically' in your question above. There is also no code you have done already. I have no idea what you want and i am really confused.

Comment: Hi Jesper, I have these code for bat file, Which is working fine. @ECHO OFF

set JAVA_CMD="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java"

%JAVA_CMD% TransferArborDeereFiles

pause  now only i want to set JAVA_CMD PATH Dynamically means it can be run from any system.

Comment: Please make your question as clear as possible! Put code you have into the question post by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43110316/edit) it! Do *not* post code in comments, because it is hardly readable due to limited formatting capabilities, and other users had to put together the relevant portions from the comments on their own in order to understand the question, which they are likely not willing to do...

Answer (score 0):

It is a big difference if an environment variable is defined with `set variable="value"` or with `set "variable=value"`. Read the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for details.

It is strongly recommended to use `set "variable=value"`, i.e. assign the string to the environment variable without double quotes and reference the value of the environment variable always enclosed in double quotes.

It looks like you use:

```
@ECHO OFF
set JAVA_CMD="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java"
%JAVA_CMD% TransferArborDeereFiles
pause
```

So to get path of `java` executable with having file extension `.exe` not specified and therefore Windows command interpreter needs to search for `java.*` with a file extension listed in local environment variable `PATHEXT`, the following batch code could be used:

```
@ECHO OFF
set JAVA_CMD="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java"
rem %JAVA_CMD% TransferArborDeereFiles
for /F "delims=" %%I in (%JAVA_CMD%) do set "JAVA_CMD_PATH=%%~dpI"
set JAVA_CMD
pause
```

This batch file just outputs the values of the environment variables `JAVA_CMD` and `JAVA_CMD_PATH`.

But much better would be:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "JAVA_CMD=%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre\bin\java.exe"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ("%JAVA_CMD%") do set "JAVA_CMD_PATH=%%~dpI"

rem Output all environment variables starting with JAVA_CMD.
set JAVA_CMD

rem "%JAVA_CMD%" TransferArborDeereFiles
rem "%JAVA_CMD_PATH%OtherScriptOrExe" "argument 1" "argument 2"

endlocal
```

This batch file should be executed in a command prompt window and not with double clicking on the batch file. Debugging a batch file in development should be always done by running it from within a command prompt window to see possible error messages output by Windows command interpreter of errors resulting in exiting batch file execution.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`